# How to prevent navigation swipe on ios devices (Nativescript)

Tags: ios, navigation, nativescript

```
onPageLoaded(args) {
  args.object.ios.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = false;
}
```

this code is not working

I will be very grateful for your help

Comment: If you put this in a try/catch block, do you get an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `enableSwipeBackNavigation` property from `Page`.

```js
import { Page } from '@nativescript/core';

...
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private page: Page
  ) {
     page.enableSwipeBackNavigation = false;
  }
}
```